# Error with the starting Karma Runner with frontend-maven-plugin

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I get the following error when trying to run the JS tests through `karma` with the `frontend-maven-plugin`

**Error:**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.19:karma (javascript tests) on project karmaTest: Failed to run task: 'karma start src/test/javascript/karma.conf.ci.js --no-colors' failed. (error code 1) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.19:karma (javascript tests) on project karmaTest: Failed to run task
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Failed to run task
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.KarmaRunMojo.execute(KarmaRunMojo.java:57)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.TaskRunnerException: 'karma start src/test/javascript/karma.conf.ci.js --no-colors' failed. (error code 1)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.NodeTaskExecutor.execute(NodeTaskExecutor.java:38)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.KarmaRunMojo.execute(KarmaRunMojo.java:51)
```

Comment: Welcome on SO! You should have a look to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question to add more info, more code and expect more answers ;)

Comment: Hello, can you provide whole devstack and pom.xml? Without it i can't be sure. I just guess that you doesn't have karma installed globaly(its not necessary, but then goal for installing node and npm has to be present). Some errors can also occures if your karma config is not there, or if directory where tests are checked doesn't exists. As I said, provide as much of your devstack as possible on bitbucket/github and I will try to help you.